# ZF2 - How to Save Uploaded File when Form is not Valid on Submit

Tags: file-upload, zend-form, zend-framework2

I have a form in ZF2 where, for example, a text box and a file input box are included. What about when the form is not valid because the text box, for example, is required and user leave it blank, how can I save on the form the previously uploaded file so that it will not be uploaded again and again when the form is invalid?

Regards,
Eli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ZF2.1 (I think), there is support for this via the post-redirect-get plugin.  The relevant documentation is here:

http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html#file-post-redirect-get-plugin

> When you cannot separate the forms, the File Post-Redirect-Get
>   Controller Plugin can be used to manage the file inputs and save off
>   valid uploads until the entire form is valid.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the way to go. I also found a relevant file upload examples on github with a sample that you mentioned (Post-Redirect-Get).  [Here's the link](https://github.com/cgmartin/ZF2FileUploadExamples/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Validation groups to validate the none-file fields separately from the file input fields:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups